# missing './lib/_stream_passthrough.js'?

Tags: angularjs

i do encounter a problem while  launching angular (yo angular):

```
       invoke   angular:controller:/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js
identical     app/scripts/controllers/main.js
identical     test/spec/controllers/main.js
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './lib/_stream_passthrough.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-karma/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/readable-stream/passthrough.js:1:80)
```

I have no idea how to solve it. I guess a module did not install but i don't understand the error message!
Anyone had this problem before and could help me ?
cheers

Angular v: v1.4.7
node -v : v4.2.1

Comment: As it is written the module can't be found.. so i decide to put the proper path: /usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/readable-stream/lib (for me) AND repeat it to the other module. maybe there is a method more straightforward.. and i let expert to give the solution